# MagicalRecord save array with relationship

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have three tables. Table Run,Pin and Note. Relationship between them are:

**1 Run N Pin**

**1 Pin N Note**

I'm trying to update Run, insert one Pin(pointing to Run) and insert N Notes(pointing to Pin). And, when user goes to another screen, I get the notes of the inserted pin. But, my problem is that is returning just one note. So, I don't know if the error is on the Update/Insert method or on find method. I tried a lot of different ways to do that, but any of them solved my problem.

*Insert/Update:*

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    // Get current Run
    Run *runDb = (Run*) [localContext objectWithID:self.idRun];

    //Create a pin
    Pin *newPin = [Pin MR_createInContext:localContext];
    [newPin setSt_description:self.txtName.text];
    [newPin setRun: runDb];
    /* Set latitude & longitude */
    newPin.dec_latitude = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    newPin.dec_longitude = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];


    /* Update run, incrementing total pins*/
    int pins = [runDb.int_total_pin intValue];
    NSNumber *pinsN = [NSNumber numberWithInt:pins+1];
    [runDb setInt_total_pin:pinsN];

    for (int i=0; i<[notes count]; i++) {
        Note *note = [Note MR_createInContext:localContext];
        [note setSt_note:[[notes objectAtIndex:i] st_note]];
        [note setPin:newPin];
    }

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(!success)
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

*Find Method (Get all notes of a pin)*

```
-(NSArray*) getNotesFromPin:(NSManagedObjectID*) pinId{
    NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pin == %@", pinId];      
    //Return notes from pin
    return [Note MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate1];

}
```

On the log, I can see that MagicalRecord is inserting 5 objects (3 notes, 1 pin and 1 run):

```
NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0xba9ba70) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 5 inserted objects
2013-11-24 19:24:28.103 MyProject[35447:1ea1b] __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke_021(0xba9ba70) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0xba9ba70): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** BACKGROUND THREAD ***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've modeled Note and Pin like so:

```
Note <-> Pin
```

That is, a one-to-one relationship. Try looking at your model, and changing Pin.note to one-to-many. This also means you'll have to change this snip to look like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<[notes count]; i++) {
    Note *note = [Note MR_createInContext:localContext];
    [note setSt_note:[[notes objectAtIndex:i] st_note]];
    [newPin addNode:note];
}
```

Comment: Pin.note was 1-1, I changed for 1-N. Note.pin is 1-1 (is correct). But, note have to point to the Pin, not? I have to implement the method addNote? Because I get an error when I tried to do that: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Note intersectsSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9da5f80'

Comment: using [note setPin:newPin] and your tip to change the relationship works! Thanks!!